# Why this django ModelForm is not valid?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-errors

I have two models:

```
ProcessDao
  ** normal fields **
  resource = models.ForeignKey(ResourceData, related_name='processes')

ResourceData
  ** Normal Fields **
```

The code below is in my views.py :

```
pdForm = ProcessDataForm(request.POST)
rd = ResourceData.objects.get(pick_date__exact = request.POST['pick_date'])
pdForm.resource = rd    <------ here is the assignment
if pdForm.is_valid():
  pdForm.save()
else:
  print 'pdForm is not valid ! ', pdForm.errors
  # print "resource is not valid."
```

Is there any way to make the pdForm valid ?

Comment: Can you try to print pdForm.errors

Comment: **pdForm is not valid !  <ul class="errorlist"><li>resource<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>**

Comment: Ah, so somehow the only field resource is empty. You may need to check `rd` to see if it is null or not.

Comment: **rd** is not null , i have checked it. thanks!

Comment: if i try to **pdForm.save(commit=False)** before **pdForm.is_valid()**,the error will be **"The ProcessData could not be created because the data didn't validate."**

Comment: `rd = ResourceData.objects.get(pick_date__exact = request.POST['pick_date'])  pdForm = ProcessDataForm(request.POST, resource = rd)` How about this?

Comment: **got an unexpected keyword argument 'resource'**

Comment: What i'm doing in my project is to assign foreign object in the override save and clean method of the form. then in the view, I just check is_valid and save.

Comment: You cannot assign fields like that in the form. You need to send the ForeignKey as part of the POST (or send another dict to the form with the correct values).

Your code isn't doing what you think its doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you work on cleaned form to assign empty fields?
Try something like:

```
if pdForm.is_valid():
    cleanform = pdForm.save(commit = False).
    cleanform.resource = rd
    cleanform.save()
```

I'm just not sure if it will work with resource being the only field in model. I'm django noob, but it works for me with assigning ForeignKey fields in many forms.

Comment: **pdForm.is_valid()** returns False, so the follow code will not be executed.And if i try to pdForm.save(commit=False) before validate,the  error will be **"The ProcessData could not be created because the data didn't validate."**

Comment: Try pdForm.fields['resource'] = rd.id before pdForm.is_valid(), then do .is_valid() and save(). I believe it's the way to change form fields before cleaning data. If that doesn't help, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: it's pdForm.fields['resource'] = rd , not rd.id

Answer (score 1):

Why would you think assigning a random attribute to a form object would make it valid? There's no point at which a form uses its instance attributes to check its validity, and nothing in the documentation implies that it does.

There are a few ways to fix this properly. First, and probably ugliest, is to copy `request.POST` and insert the id of the matching object into there. (You need to copy it, as the original instance is immutable).

A much better way is to exclude the field from the form altogether (via the form's `Meta` class) and in the `is_valid` clause do this:

```
object = pdForm.save(commit=False)
rd = ResourceData.objects.get(pick_date__exact = pdForm.cleaned_data['pick_date'])
object.resource = rd  
object.save()
```